# Install the SSL module on Python 3.6 without rebuilding

Tags: python, ssl, build, installation

So a few hours ago I built python (3.6) from source on a raspberry pi (raspbian). Now trying to install modules I find out I do not have the SSL module. Looking around at other questions there seams to be no other way other than to rebuild it with the arg --with-ssl or something. 
I don't want to do that again as it took about 3 and a half hours to complete. Unless you can multi-thread the make process across all four cores? However the pi thermals will probably hold it back.
I there a way to install it? On python 2 you could with `pip install ssl`, me been stupid tried `pip3 install ssl` but that is still python 2 ssl module so throws syntax errors. Then tried with `ssl3` but that does not exist.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to rebuild then, i have deleted the python directory so...

Answer (score 1):

In standard python 3 installation ssl is considered a built-in, so there's no option to install it.

Probably rebuilding is the only solution then.